# How to access global variable in using coffeescript in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I want to set and get value of an object in coffee script. My Code looks like

```
global.fbUserData = ''

unless fbUserData

  #Use facebook strategy
  passport.use new FacebookStrategy(
  clientID: 'XXXXXX'
  clientSecret: 'XXXXXX'
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:com/auth/facebook/callback'
  , (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) ->
      fbUserData.name = profile.displayName
      fbUserData.email = profile.emails[0].value
    done null, profile
  )
```

And When in Facebook Callback route I want to access the `global fbUserData` object, it returns me undefined like

```
app.get "/auth/facebook/callback", passport.authenticate("facebook",
failureRedirect: "/user"
), (req, res) ->
     res.send "User Name " + fbUserData.name + " User Email " + fbUserData.email
```

Here `fbUserData.name` and `fbUserData.email` is undefined. How can I set variable value and get where it is needed on same page?

Comment: If you use a global like that every person who signs in will overwrite the previous user's data. Why do you feel this needs to be a global?

Comment: @loganfsmyth My ultimate goal is to set some values in an object and then get where it is needed as described in question. How can I do that?

Comment: You should not use a global for this anyway. Is it possible that you're running into some problem with asynchrony?